# T1 font encoding and math fonts

Tags: math-mode, font-encodings

For specific reasons, I'd like to typeset an equation in `\mathrm{...}`. Also, the document uses T1 font encoding. Now a greek Delta in an equation gets typeset as "`" instead unless I use OT1 font encoding (which I don't want). Of course, I could wrap the parts before and after the` \Delta`separately in`\mathrm{...}`, but this becomes quite awkward.

```
\documentclass{beamer} %

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
  Plain \textbackslash{}Delta: $\Delta$
  
  \textbackslash{}mathrm: $\mathrm{\Delta}$
  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there another fix for this?

Comment: You are probably misusing `\mathrm`. Why do you want to use if for a whole equation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font set up in `beamer` is somewhat non-standard (to get as much as possible in sans serif). If you want a more 'normal' arrangement, do

```
\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}
```

which will solve your issue here.