# T1 font encoding, beamer, and mathrm

Tags: beamer, math-mode, font-encodings

Beamer uses a sans-serif font to typeset math. While I like the aesthetics of it, in a math context I find capital I and capital Pi significantly harder to read without the serifs. Without T1 encoding, I can write `\mathrm{\Pi}` to cheat my way out. With T1 encoding, however, Pi is typeset as ´´ instead.

I am aware that this problem is identical to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278406/t1-font-encoding-and-math-fonts), but I am looking for a different answer. Specifically, I do not wish to replace all math with a serif font, only that one character. Can this be achieved somehow?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\let\oldPi\Pi
\renewcommand{\Pi}{\mathrm{\oldPi}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\Pi$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, I declare a math alphabet `\oldmathrm` to use `OT1` encoding.  Then I can access it for `\Pi` redefinition.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\oldmathrm}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\oldPi\Pi
\renewcommand{\Pi}{\oldmathrm{\oldPi}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\Gamma\Pi$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted access to both the sans `\Pi` as well as the `rm` version, then don't `\renewcommand\Pi`, but instead just use `\Pi` and `\oldmathrm{\Pi}` in your document.

Another way, and I am not sure which way is preferred (i.e., uses less resources) is just to declare a symbol font, and use slot 5 from that font for `\Pi`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\DeclareSymbolFont{oldrm}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathord}{oldrm}{"5}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\Sigma\Pi$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]